# Helper syntax in ASP vNext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

As i can see in ASP 5 [@helper](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site) cannot be used anymore in .cshtml. What is equivalent to @helper in vNext?

Answer (score 0):

[`It was removed`](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/281). It was a bad idea from day 1 anyways. As far as a replacement is concerned, well, there are partial views.

Comment: Partial views aren't an adequate replacement though. It's a shame that we're being forced to build HTML with StringBuilders of all things. TagHelpers don't improve on this.

Comment: Why do you think that partial views aren't an adequate replacement? If you want to avoid StringBuilders, partial views are a good alternative.

Comment: Say I want build a single `ValidatedEditorFor` which accepts an expression and HtmlAttributes and return a nicely formatted block of `div`, `label`, `editor`, `validationError`, etc. https://gist.github.com/tboby/8b2587a94a6e494d955e#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: And what prevents you from writing this `ValidatedEditorFor` helper as an extension method in a static class in which you would simply invoke the `htmlHelper.Partial` method in order to render the corresponding partial view which will contain your markup?

Comment: As far as I can tell there's no reliable way to pass multiple `htmlAttributes` parameters to a partial view from an extension method.

Comment: No, but you could pass a view model which is far more powerful. Because this view model can have whatever properties you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100156/discussion-between-thomas-boby-and-darin-dimitrov).